# Going from object List to database

Tags: c#, java, sql, sql-server, database

I'm just getting started on databases and could use some help.
I currently have a program that handles car parking permits. You can add cars to the system, and associate a car with a permit. Up until now it was creating objects and storing them in 2 Lists: Car and Permits.

For example, my Car class is simply this:

```
class Car{
    private string regNumber;
    private string make;
    private string colour;
    private string owner;

    //constructor, getters, setters, ...
}
```

The Permit class is similar. It just has a permitID and a car registration.

I'm now making the jump to a database instead of using Lists to store the data.

However, as far as I can tell, using a database makes both of my classes redundant. Each tuple in the Car table will contain exactly what my Car objects contained, and I can do a join query to get Car data from a given permitID.

Is there a need for my classes anymore?

Comment: So is this java, c# or database question? And I would say you should do 1:N database for 1 permit can have multiple cars. You would do it with table for permits, table for cars and table for relation data, with permit id and car id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider a class that is a car
Car { long unique_id; int permit_id; ... String color; }
where unique_id is the primary key from a cars table.
since the way you are explaining it in the question.  Then to parse the SQL results consider using a simplified [DAO Pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm) to read the database into the application and use it.

Given the example, I am not sure why you would need two tables, a Cars table with a permit id value should be sufficient unless there is a reusable pool of permits, in which case you could create a static table with all permits in it.